# Не совпадают цвета меток и цвета круговой диаграммы на группировках Яндекс карты

Tags: яндекс-карты

Вывожу объекты на карту. У объектов есть характеристика, в зависимости от нее я меняю цвет метки от красного до зеленого (типа плохие, хорошие).
Цвета меток использую стандартные через preset:

islands#greenStretchyIcon

islands#blueStretchyIcon

islands#orangeStretchyIcon

islands#redStretchyIcon

[image: Текст]

**Как видно на фото - синий и зеленый цвета (на иконках группировки) не совпадают с цветами одиночных иконок, почему так?**

Вот мой код:

```js
var map = (function() {
  var _private = {
    'geoMap': null,
    'moscow': [55.755381, 37.619044],
    'init': function(el) {
    _private.geoMap = new ymaps.Map(el, {
      center: _private.moscow,
      zoom: 9,
      controls: [],
    },
    {
      suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
      suppressObsoleteBrowserNotifier: true,
    }
    );
        _private.geoMap.controls.add('zoomControl');
    _private.geoMap.controls.add(
        new ymaps.control.SearchControl({useMapBounds: true}), {top: 6, left: 250});
    },
    'setCenter': function(res, zoom) {
    _private.geoMap.setCenter(res, zoom);
    },
    'setClusterer': function(res) {
  if(res.length){
    var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
        // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
        clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
        // Радиус диаграммы в пикселях.
        clusterIconPieChartRadius: 15,
        // Радиус центральной части макета.
        clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: 10,
        // Ширина линий-разделителей секторов и внешней обводки диаграммы.
        clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 1,
        // Определяет наличие поля balloon.
        hasBalloon: false
    });
    if(window.section && section == 9){
    clusterer.options.set({
    gridSize: 512
  });
  }
    var placemarks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([res[i].geo_lat, res[i].geo_long], {
            iconContent: '<a href="' + res[i].url + '" style="text-decoration: none;">' + res[i].text + '</a>'
        }, {
            preset: res[i].color
        });
        placemarks.push(placemark);
    }

    clusterer.add(placemarks);
    _private.geoMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
    res=null;
    if(window.clustereradded){clustereradded=2}
  }else{
            if(window.clustereradded){clustereradded=3}
  }
    }
  };
  return {
    init: function(el) {
    _private.init(el);
    },
    setCenter: function(res, zoom) {
    _private.setCenter(res, zoom);
    },
    setClusterer: function(res) {
    _private.setClusterer(res);
    }
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось недостаточно просто выбрать дефолтный маркер, нужно еще и жестко прописать его цвет, тогда цвета на группировке будут нормальные

```
        preset: 'islands#circleIcon',
        iconColor: '#4d7198'
```